# Find the next character in a string

Tags: ruby

Here is a string,

```
test = "IXIVDL"
```

How to find which character comes right after "I" in the string?
And whether it is only "X" or "V" or any other?

For eg.

`"IDXCN"` is an invalid string because `"I"` id followed by `"D"`

`"IXD"` is a valid string because `"I"`is followed by `"X"`

`"IVIX"` is a valid string because `"I"` is followed by `"V"` or `"X"`

`"DIDIX"` is invalid string because `"I"` is followed by `"D"`

`"DXI"` is valid

I do not want any string output. The result should be either true or false or nil.

Comment: You seem to have been in a rush to select an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how regular expressions work here: [Class: Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html)

This should solve your doubt, notice how the index of the valid substring is returned when it exists:

```
'IXIVDL' =~ /I[XV]/    # returns 0
'IDXCN'  =~ /I[XV]/    # returns nil
'IXD'    =~ /I[XV]/    # returns 0
'IVIX'   =~ /I[XV]/    # returns 2
```

If you need to know whether **every** `I` is immediately followed by either an `X` or a `V` you can use instead:

```
'DID­IX' =~ /I[^X­V]/
```

which returns `nil` for valid strings (notice it accepts `I` at the end of the string).

Comment: This is incorrect because 'DIDIX' =~ /I[XV]/ # returns 3 which is invalid. "I" can only be followed by "X" or "V"

Comment: So even though `I` is immediately followed by `X` in that string, you need it to fail because in other parts of the string `I` is immediately followed by `D`? if that is the case, check my updated answer.

Comment: "I" at the end of the string is okay. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
def validate(str)    
  res = str.scan(/(?<=I).?/)
  puts "String is #{(res-['X','V']).empty? ? "valid" : "invalid"}"
  res.each do |c|
    if c.empty?
      puts "I at end of string is invalid"
    else
      puts "#{c} following I is #{c=~/[XV]/ ? "valid" : "invalid"}"
    end
  end
end

validate "IXIVDLIZRI"
String is invalid
X following I is valid
V following I is valid
Z following I is invalid
I at end of string is invalid

validate "IXIVDLIV"
String is valid
X following I is valid
V following I is valid
V following I is valid
```

`/(?<=I)./` matches any character following an "I". `(?<=I)` is a positive lookbehind. Change the `puts` messages to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that you can run to test your string, it will output `Invalid String` if there is no `I` or the `I` is not followed by the correct letter as you have specified. Otherwise it will output `Valid String, I is followed by...` whichever letters you have chosen. In this case `X` or `V`

```
def find_I(test)
  index_of_I = test.split('').find_index { |letter| letter == 'I' }
  if index_of_I.nil? || test[index_of_I + 1].nil?
    return "Invalid String"
  elsif test[index_of_I + 1] =~ /[XV]/
    return "Valid String, I followed by #{test[index_of_I + 1]}"
  else
    return "Invalid String"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most simple solution.

```
def find_string_digits(str)
  str =~ /IX/ || str =~ /IV/ ? true : false
end
```

It's using regex to match a certain pattern within the string, in this case whether an 'X' directly follows an 'I', or if a 'V' directly follows an 'I', and if so returns true, otherwise returns false. On a side note, if you wanted to check that say the 3rd letter after the 'I' was an 'X', you would match /I..X/ and so on.

Hope that helps.